# Guide to helping with mapping using laser data

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, 2d-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

does anyone here know about some kind of tutorial where I can learn how to use laser data to build a map.

I've recently been working on an EKF SLAM algorithm project, but I have no idea how to build a map using sensor data.

Any help would be really appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251092/guide-to-helping-with-mapping-using-laser-data/) by [AkaTomo93](https://answers.ros.org/users/28379/akatomo93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-01-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Start here. It is simplest way I have seen: http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2017-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0